# Accessing IP restricted external services from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Lets say I have a service running clustered on N ec2 instances. On top of that I have Amazon EKS and Elastic Loadbalancer. There is a service not managed by me running outside of AWS where I have an account that my services in AWS are using via HTTP requests. When I made an account to this external service I was asked for an IP (range) of services which will be using this external service. There is my problem. Currently lets say I have 3 EC2 instances with Elastic IP addresses (which are static), so I can just give those three IP addresses to this external service provider and everything works just fine. But in the future I might add more EC2 instances to scale out and whitelisting new IP addresses in the external service is a pain. In some cases those whitelist change requests may take for a week to approve by the external service provider and I dont have that time. Even further, accessing this external service is the only reason I go for static IPs for the EC2 instances. So if possible I would ditch the Elastic IPs.

So my question is how could I act so that if I make requests outside of the AWS in a random instance in my cluster, external service providers would always see the same IP address for me as a service consumer?

*Disclaimer: I actually dont have that setup running yet, but I am in the middle of doing research if that would be a feasible option. So forgive me if my question sounds dumb for some obvious reason*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [Network address translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)  can solve your problem.   A [NAT gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) with Elastic IP, used for rerouting all traffic through it.

NAT gateway provided by AWS as service can be expensive if your data traffic is big, so you can make your own [NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html), but that is bit complicated to set up and maintain.

The main difference between NAT gateway and NAT instance are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-comparison.html)

The example bellow is assumed that EC2 instances are in private subnet, but it doesn't have to be a case.

[image: simplified solution using NAT gateway]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a proxy server in your environment with an Elastic IP. Basically you can use something like NGINX/Apache and configure it with an elastic IP. Configure the webserver to provide an endpoint to your EC2 instances, and doing a proxy pass to the external endpoint.

For high availability, you can manage a proxy in each availability zone, ideally configured using an auto scaling group to keep at leaset one instance alive in each AZ. Going through this approach, you will need to make sure that you assign the public IP from your elastic IP pool.

Generally, hostnames are better alternative to the IP addresses to avoid such situations as they can provide a static endpoint no matter what is the IP behind. Not sure whether you can explore that path with your external API provider. It can be challenging when there is static IP based routing/whitelisting rules in place.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) is for.   NAT Gateways have an Elastic IP attached and allow the instances inside a VPC to make outbound connections, transparently, using the gateway's static address.